# if else recursion worst time complexity

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I have some trouble to figure out the worst time complexity of below code.
*(This is not a homework, see https://leetcode.com/problems/integer-replacement/description/.)*

```
int recursion (int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 0;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return recursion(n/2) + 1
    } else {
        return min(recursion(n / 2 + 1) + 1, recursion(n - 1)) + 1;
   }
}
```

The only thing I know is when `N == 2 ^ k(k > 0)`, worst time complexity is `O(logN)`.
However, I am unclear when `N` is not `2^k`. Because even `number / 2` can still get odd number. Some people said it is still `O(LogN)`, but I am not convinced.

I know the code is not best solution, just wanna analyze the time complexity. I tried recursion tree and aggregate analysis, seems not help.

Comment: Your else case has a wrong statement it should've been `(n+1)/2`

Comment: @BlackMamba . Hi, (n + 1) would overflow.  But I have other errors.  Updated.Thanks very much

Comment: I saw the leetcode problem statement. I do *not* see how, in its first two revisions, your last branch (the one with `min` selecting between alternatives) relates to it - it shouldn't be part of "an `else`" if "the `then`" terminates with an unconditional `return`, anyway.

Comment: It has a simple pragmatic solution.  If it is worse than O(logN) then it always blows the stack on a big value for N.  So run it once with INT_MAX and if it doesn't crash then it is QED.  Whether that is leet is not terribly relevant at SO :)  Plenty leet enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `n` is even, we know that `T(n) = T(n/2) + 1`, and if `n` is odd we know that
`T(n) = T(n/2 + 1) + T(n-1) + 1`. In the latter case, as `n` is odd we know that `n-1` must be even. if `n/2 + 1` is even `T(n) = T(n/4) + T(n/2) + 3` and if `n/2 + 1` is odd `T(n) = 2*T(n/4) + T(n/2) + 3`.

From the above discussion, in the worst case `T(n)` is defined based on the `T(n/2)` and `T(n/4)` in a general case. From [Akra-Bazzi Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) we can say, `T(n) = O(n^((log(1+sqrt(5))-log(2))/log(2))) ~ O(n^0.69)` (from the first case) and `T(n) = O(n)` from the second case (which `n/2 + 1` is odd).

However, for the more tight complexity, we should scrutinize more in our analysis.

Comment: Hi,  the Akra-Bazzi blew my mind.  I was applying this to T(n) = T(n/4) + T(n/2).

Comment: If `n` is odd then `n/2 + 1` can be odd or even - consider n=7 and n=9.

Comment: @OmG and if `n=9` then `n/2+1` is equal `5`.